# how to change the method into .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
   import pandas as pd
   
   f=open("xyz.csv",'w')
   df=pd.DataFrame(sq3row)
   df.to_csv(f)
```

i am using above code to write sq3lite output rows to .csv file based on conditions
but instead of row wise the output is writing in columns for ex data's to be written from row[0] to row[11] is writing to col[0] to col[11] and second output row is writing from col[12] to col[24] likewise

how to write this in row wise like col[1]:row[0] to row[11]
for next col[2]: row[0] to row[11]

Answer (score 0):

```
## I think you are trying to transpose your df    
df = df.T
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use transpose function to convert rows into columns and vice versa.

```
import pandas as pd
f=open("xyz.csv",'w')
df=pd.DataFrame(sq3row)
df.to_csv(f)
df.transpose()
```